# How to pass an element from a array of strings to a thread?

Tags: c, arrays, string, multithreading

Needed some assistance in solving a problem of "passing an element from a array of strings to a thread". My code is after this text. I declared an array of strings in the `main` function and then passed one element of the array to a thread. In the thread I typecast it back to char* type and then print, but it prints garbage values. Would be grateful for the solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *agent(void *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    pthread_t agent_t[3];
    char *agent_colour[3] = {"Red","White","Brown"};

    for(i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++) {
        pthread_create(&agent_t[i], 0, agent, &agent_colour[i]);        
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++) {
        pthread_join(agent_t[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}

void *agent(void *arg) {
    char *colour = (char*)arg;
    int x;
    srand(time(NULL));
    x = rand() % 5 + 1;
    sleep(x);
    printf("\n My name is Agent %s\n", colour);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

My output is:

```
 My name is Agent � @

 My name is Agent � @

 My name is Agent � @
```

Comment: So many superfluous casts from and to `void *`. Also, string literals should be declared as `const char *`, not `char *`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
pthread_create(&agent_t[i], 0, agent, agent_colour[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong in the `pthread_create` call

```
&agent_colour[i]
```

you just want to pass the string

```
agent_colour[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

agent_colour is an array of pointer. So just pass like this agent_colour[i] in pthread create.