# How do I pass this array of c strings correctly?

Tags: c, arrays, char, parameter-passing, cstring

I have my array of C-Strings declared as:

```
char *argv[MAXARGS];
```

MAXARGS basically just tells us how many c strings are in the array for indexing purposes.
I want to pass it to this function below...

```
int builtin_cmd(char **argv)
```

but nothing seems to go through, I called the function like this.

```
    char *argv[MAXARGS];

    builtin_cmd(argv);
```

but once i get into the function `builtin_cmd` and try to print using

```
printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
```

it prints nothing.... but when i do this before calling the function...

```
char *argv[MAXARGS];
printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
//builtin_cmd(argv);
```

it will print the first C string in the array of c strings just fine.
My thoughts are that I am passing the structure incorrecly and I would like to know the correct way to pass it to the function.

EDIT:

```
int builtin_cmd(char **argv);
int main()
{
    char *argv[128];
    //put 'quit' into argv[0]..
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]); //prints 'quit'
    builtin_cmd(argv);
}
int builtin_cmd(char **argv)
{
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]); //prints nothing
}
```

The problem is, again, that I cant seem to get argv into the function.  It also compiles with no errors or warnings.

Comment: Please post a minimal, real example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: As written, [I see no reason this doesn't work](http://ideone.com/ZNEOFy). Post the *real* code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the prototype of the builtin_cmd is correct? Usually one would expect something of the form `builtin_cmd(int argc, char* argv[])` . How does the built-in command know how many arguments you are passing otherwise?

Comment: The similar concept is more described in this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648346/how-to-pass-an-element-from-a-array-of-strings-to-a-thread

Comment: @WhozCraig awesome job showing "this is not your problem" with working code that implements what is shown in the question. I agree with your conclusion - whatever is wrong with the code is not what is shown here.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown how you initialize the array, and that's the crucial part.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void builtin_cmd(char **argv)
{
     while (*argv != NULL)
         printf("%s\n", *argv++);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *argv[] = { "abc", "def", "ghi", NULL };
    builtin_cmd(argv);
    return 0;
}
```

This code uses a sentinel value, the null pointer, to mark the end of the data.  The alternative is to pass the number of strings in the array as a separate argument.  When you use `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, you actually have both mechanisms in use; `argv[argc] == NULL` so there is the count and then sentinel value.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass an array of charecter pointers to an function so your function declratation should be `builtin_cmd(char* argv[])`.Here's an sample example to pass array of pointers to an function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void fill_strings(char *str[], int nstrings)
{
    int i;
    for ( i=0; i < nstrings; i++)
        strcpy(str[i], "hello world");
}

void print_strings(char *str[], int nstrings)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < nstrings; i++)
        printf("string %d: %s\n", i, str[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *index[10];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        index[i] = malloc(20);
    }
    fill_strings(index, 10);
    print_strings(index, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing your input on the command line you need to tell the compiler that you're using the parameters that are passed into main from the runtime.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
```

That should allow you to pass "quit" as the first parameter properly. Otherwise, as the others say, how you fill a "C vector" is important.